# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am following the next documentation "https://pysource.com/2018/09/25/simple-shape-detection-opencv-with-python-3/" and I have the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/Proyectos/Detecciondeobjetos/Untitled-1.py", line 9, in <module>
    for cnt in contours:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX

img = cv2.imread("123.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, contours = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0), 5)
    x = approx.ravel()[0]
    y = approx.ravel()[1]
    if len(approx) == 3:
        cv2.putText(img, "Triangle", (x, y), font, 1, (0))
    elif len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.putText(img, "Rectangle", (x, y), font, 1, (0))
    elif len(approx) == 5:
        cv2.putText(img, "Pentagon", (x, y), font, 1, (0))
    elif 6 < len(approx) < 15:
        cv2.putText(img, "Ellipse", (x, y), font, 1, (0))
    else:
        cv2.putText(img, "Circle", (x, y), font, 1, (0))

cv2.imshow("shapes", img)

cv2.imshow("Threshold", threshold)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

this is the image i am using
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`contours == None`

As such, your for-loop...

```
for cnt in contours:
     pass
```

... is the same as...

```
for cnt in None:
    pass
```

`None` is not a container. `None` does not have 2 or 3 or 100 elements that you can loop over. The following is the signature for `cv.findContours`

```
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]] )
```

You called it as:

```
_, contours = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

I think you might have swapped the order of `_, contours` and `contours, _`

Anyway, it looks like the `hierarchy` return value is `None`

Comment: ok i tried to do just a print (), but in the console show 'none', why is this happen?